# Why would Google's map of areas affected by Hurricane Harvey have advisories for the west coast and other far away areas?

Tags: meteorology, tropical-cyclone, extreme-weather

[image]

What behavior of this hurricane would lead to advisories for the west coast and even parts of Canada and Alaska, when the hurricane is in the South?

I have little experience in meteorology or any of the earth sciences really, so I am interested in how this would affect the weather or other conditions far away from where the hurricane is severe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]It seems like there is more than just a hurricane going on. According to the [National Weather Service](http://weather.gov) there are excessive heat advisories, gale warnings, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this map included other types of advisories and warnings also. The areas on these maps match up perfectly, so I believe this is the answer.

Comment: The basic idea: Google, while improving (such as notifying you of active important warnings when you Google a town) still isn't great at compiling pertinent information.  They're getting better, but got a ways to go.  Then again, most do.